# How to always show combobox in data grid

Tags: wpf

**WPF Application**

In datagrid,if I use **DataGridComboBoxColumn** to show Combobox,it is only show when I double click the cell enter edit status.

I want to show the combobox all the time， and don't need to double click the cell.
How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and add a `ComboBox` to its `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="..." />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="..." />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to updated the DataGrid when this combobox value is changed?